# Multiple Metrics in Keras (in R)

Tags: r, keras, lstm

I'm trying to compile a model in Keras (in R) using multiple metrics. The reason for this is to decide which metric works best in evaluating the models created. The code which works for a single metric being:

```
model %>% compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics = metric_mean_absolute_error())
```

I've seen in python code like

```
metrics = [metric_mean_absolute_error(), accuracy()]
```

work well, but in R the brackets give an error. I've tried searching for a way to do this in R, but haven't found luck anywhere. The error is below:

```
Error in source(file = file, local = envir, echo = echo, encoding = encoding) :
tune.R:30:12: unexpected '['
29: loss = 'mean_squared_error',
30: metrics = [
```

Answer (score 1):

In R you can create a list with the `list()` function.

```r
model %>%
  compile(
    optimizer = 'Adam',
    loss = 'mean_squared_error',
    metrics = list(metric_mean_absolute_error(),
                   'accuracy')
  )
```